# Batch conversion of point feature class to raster

Tags: raster, point, convert, feature-class, batch

I have a point feature class that contains over 100 columns (variables) of data. I would like to convert each column to a raster. The reason for doing this is to create a multiband raster that can be subject to Principal Components analysis in ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I have now solved this issue using the batch feature to raster tool in ArcGIS Pro